# Tint a white-on-transparent image with CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image that's white with a transparent background; I'd like to be able to dynamically color/tint the image on hover to another color.

My first thought was to use `background-blend-mode` to `multiply` a solid red image with my white-on-transparent image to get a red-on-transparent image.  Unfortunately, this doesn't give the desired behavior and instead gives me a solid red box.  Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/wcL2exa4/58/

I've looked into CSS `mask` but that also doesn't seem to do what I want.  How can I easily turn my white image into a colored one?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `mix-blend-mode` on a pseudoelement. I've used `multiply` and `screen` in the example below

```js
document.getElementById('c').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const mode = e.target.checked ? 'screen' : 'multiply';
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--blend-mode', mode);
})
```

```css
:root {
  --blend-mode: multiply;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

#constellation {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: url("https://storage.googleapis.com/astrology-images/constellations/aries-white.png");
}

#constellation:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  mix-blend-mode: var(--blend-mode);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="constellation" class="bg">
  </div>
</div>
<input id="c" type="checkbox"><label for="c">Red Background</label>
```

Comment: Is `mix-blend-mode: multiply` the functioning part here?  I tried that in my jsfiddle and it doesn't seem to work: https://jsfiddle.net/wcL2exa4/81/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/80sq4zar/ - The property is applied to a pseudoelement that is shown on hover. You should be able to change the background colour of the pseudoelement to whatever you need.

Comment: that's a copy of my jsfiddle; it's exactly the same and doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

There is a way but it's a bit weird

```
filter: brightness(0.5) sepia(1) hue-rotate(50deg)
```

Change the brightness and hue rotate till you get the colour you want.

Comment: Since his image is white, `hue-rotate` do nothing.

Comment: Is there a way to get a *specific* color this way?  What color does `sepia` get me?

Answer (score 0):

Are all background image white ?
You may do it by changing the default image to a red version, and apply some `filter` to it to get it white.

Comment: They're all white -- I want them to be able to change to different colors (red, blue, green, etc.) so going from red -> white doesn't help me here.

Comment: But you can do red (#FF0000) to many others colors.

Comment: This playground may help to get the right configuration for each needed. Just change the CSS in "Background Image" textarea.

Comment: Did you forget the link?

Comment: Yes sorry : https://codepen.io/adrianparr/pen/EBHbi (just change `#colour-wheel { background-color: ...}` to your default color.)